# Highchart Basicline

Tags: json, highcharts

According to my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809850/highcharts-basic-line-with-json-for-multiple-y-axes)
 i have tried something, and my fiddle is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/itsfromnaveen/vntfy)
  But i want to be output as like below

[image]

`i.e` x axis contains monthly reports

my ajax code is

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(point) {

            var chartSeriesData = [];
            var chartCategory = [];


            $.each(point, function(i, item) {
                var series_name = item.resultDate;
                var series_data = item.y;
                var cagory = series_name;

                var series = {
                    name: series_name,
                    data: item.y
                };
                chartSeriesData.push(series);
                chartCategory.push(series_name);
            });
            var chartingOptions = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: chartCategory
                },
                series: chartSeriesData
            };

            chartingOptions = $.extend({}, jugalsLib.getBasicChartOptions(), chartingOptions);
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
        }
    });
```

Thanking you....

Answer (score 1):

In your parser, you create many series, because you initialize series in points loop. So you should prepare series earlier than points loop. Then add points to correct serie (in this case first or second serie).